# 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' is found. But path is correct. Working in other Applications

Tags: c#, file, filepath

[image]

Provided path is correct. It is working in other solution. But here, it is searching the mentioned file in bin/debug folder. but its in root directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on your "TestFile1.txt" file in your Solution Explorer and go to its properties, you will see something similar to this:

[image]

Change the "Copy to Output Directory" from Do Not Copy to Always Copy.
What this will do is always make sure your 'TestFile1.txt' is copied to your Bin folder.

Answer (score 2):

The path is not correct, you are specifying the path in your `Debug/bin` folder like the exception wrote you. The correct path of your file is in your project folder.

```
string str= "../../TextFile1.txt"; //This will work.
```

Comment: No, i have specified str="Textfile.txt". which is in current directory where program.cs is placed. it should work.

Comment: @Raghu The program is executed from Debug/bin so when you specify TextFile1.txt only you look in this folder. You should write it like I show you, in this case you will take the file.

Comment: It works, but why do i  need to use ../../ , when my file and program.cs are in same folder.which is working in other applications.

Comment: Maybe because in those other applications the file to be read is also copied to the bin/Debug/ folder on build?

Comment: @Raghu ../ this means go in previous directory, when you wrote it twice you will go twice and this will be your project directory. You can do like Jason H and copy the file in your output directory.

Comment: @Sentry won't it work dependent on the way it is executed... like if you are running in debug mode, it will check in debug/bin, but in release mode directly in bin??

Comment: @Anand For release it would be in "bin/Release/" or whatever folder you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Raghu, 
The path in your str, you will have to specify full path. 
You have only mentioned the filename without path, so it is searching in debug as you are running in debug mode. 
Use the path using AppDomain

Comment: "cause and solution. ASAP" :-)